# Installation order for SQL server and visual studio

Tags: asp.net

I would like to install visual studio 2010 IDE into my windows8 PC. My questions are:

1. Can someone recommend the free versions of sql server and visual studio 2010. I want to work on the ASP web application for my Masters final project. So, looking for free versions of the software.
2. Also, please let me know the installation order for vs and sql server. 
   I got confused after reading a lot about the order of installation.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You will want visual web developer express http://www.asp.net/vwd and also sql server express https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

install in whatever order you want, i would install sql server first and then web developer

Comment: I read somewhere that the installation order is important otherwise the database connections wouldn't work properly. If I install sql server first should I do the custom installation for vs, as it downloads the plugins for sql.

Comment: You should look at the date of the article first because that used to be the case years ago.  In the modern development era, it doesn't really matter.  Also, check the source of the article.  If it's not from MS, I would not take the word of the article(s) as the final say.  Also, you should look at @win's answer as Microsoft is really trying to put as many development products in the hands of students as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a student and have **.edu** email account, you can register and download Professional Versions at [Microsoft DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/).

1. [Visual Studio Professional 2013](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=72)
2. [SQL Server 2012](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=43)
3. Then watch ASP.Net trainings at [PluralSight](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=21)

Comment: How long can I use these professional versions. Is it for just couple of months??

Comment: There is no expiration date, because it comes with valid license keys. You use them a long as you are a student.

Answer (score 0):

You should have what you need if you download the VS web express (probably the 2013 version!) and the ms sql express packages.

I would start with the sql installation. I know VS will probably try installing the sql server if you install that first, but I've had better luck with doing it the way around.